# Support unknown critical X509 certificate extension in Windows or .NET

Tags: .net, windows, x509, x509certificate2, x509chain

I'm trying to validate a certificate chain in .NET (4.5.2) with `X509Chain`, and my chain will not validate because the leaf certificate has a critical extension (Apple Pay) that is not recognised by, presumably, the underlying security engine that Windows provides the .NET framework.

Currently I can work around this by ensuring that the only errors with the certificate chain are the errors that seem to be caused by this extension:

- one item in the leaf's `ChainElementStatus` with `Status` of `X509ChainStatusFlags.InvalidExtension`
- one item in the leaf's `ChainElementStatus` with `Status` of `(X509ChainStatusFlags)0x08000000` (amusingly the IDE gives this the name `HasNotSupportedCriticalExtension` but that value doesn't exist in the enum; I assume this is due to .NET framework changes)
- that the leaf does have a `Critical` extension with the expected OID

This seems messy, though. I would far rather tell the framework to expect this extension upfront than to verify that it failed for the correct reasons.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744908/certificate-has-unsupported-critical-extension) on how to achieve this with BouncyCastle (although it involves changing the source) but can't find a way to do this with the built-in `X509Chain` class.

I also can't find a way to "install" this extension into Windows to make it recognise it.

Is there a way to do this? Or is either stripping the extension or making the framework recognise it a worse "bad idea" than letting it fail and verifying exactly why it did?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to acheive this in elegant way with CryptoAPI (`X509Chain` is just a saimple wrapper over CryptoAPI). You may need to research for options available in BouncyCastle.

Comment: @Crypt32 yeah, I'm leaning that way myself. I'm having some luck with BC (without changing the source!) but would rather not take on the dependency, and I'm still not sure there's not a "proper" way I should be handling the extension.

Comment: "proper" way is written in RFC and implemented in CryptoAPI -- reject cert with unknown critical extension. I know this doesn't help you much, but that's all I can offer in your case. Even underlying CryptoAPI functions doesn't expose requested functionality, so .NET BCL isn't the tool you need and I don't have experience in BC.